# How to display custom image type on shopping cart page?

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, shopping-cart, custom-attributes

I have created a custom image media type "custom" using this tutorial:

http://www.pixafy.com/blog/2012/12/adding-a-fourth-image-position-to-the-admin-for-a-magento-product/

Currently magento shows thumbnail image type on shopping cart page but I want custom type image on the page.
How can I do this?

I have tried this:

```
    /magento/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml

 <img src="<?php echo $this->getProductCustom()->resize(180); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductName()) ?>" />
```

after trying Siarhey Uchukhlebau's answer:

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_item->getProduct(), 'custom')->resize(180);?>" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductName()) ?>" />
```

I got this error:

```
Image file was not found.

Trace:
#0 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Image.php(166): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Image->setBaseFile(NULL)
#1 /var/www/html/magento/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml(38): Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image->init(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), 'custom')
#2 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/html/m...')
#3 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/rwd/de...')
#4 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#5 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#6 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Abstract.php(174): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#7 /var/www/html/magento/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml(147): Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Abstract->getItemHtml(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item))
#8 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/html/m...')
#9 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/rwd/de...')
#10 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#11 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#12 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#13 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#14 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#15 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#16 /var/www/html/magento/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/page/1column.phtml(55): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#17 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/html/m...')
#18 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/rwd/de...')
#19 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#20 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#21 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#22 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#23 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php(181): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#24 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Checkout_CartController->indexAction()
#25 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#26 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#27 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#28 /var/www/html/magento/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#29 /var/www/html/magento/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#30 {main}
```

after this I set up place holder image for this custom attribute from this path:

```
System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Product Image Placeholders
```

and now I am getting the place holder image but not the actual image that I selected as "custom"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Load product by id (from quote item):

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId());
```

get custom image from loaded product:

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'product_custom')->resize(180);?>" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductName()) ?>" />
```

The issue was that the product initially had no your custom attribute, this is the reason why it could not display it.
[image: Product conf]
[image: In Cart]

Comment: I have tried your code but getting error.  I have used "product_custom" and "custom" but no one is working for me.

error:

There has been an error processing your request

Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 513180672

Comment: please show content of the var/report/513180672 file here

Comment: @UchukhlebauI
have added the error message in my post.

Comment: @UchukhlebauI I have updated my post.

Comment: i’ve updated my answer

Comment: thanks. Can you please tell me why this code is not working on that page: $_item = $this->getItem();
Zend_Debug::dump($_item);exit;

Comment: This code works properly on this page at my side https://gyazo.com/a4d1bea807028942c87528b69fd2341a